# How to center radar chart ticks when changing start angle of chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

*Edit
Looks like what i was looking for to them was a bug which they ref'd and *fixed here.
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/4682

I've created a radar chart using chart.js and always want the flat side of the chart to be horizontal. I set the startAngle under options to 750 to rotate the chart so it meets that req. Unfortunately the tick marks also rotate and stick to the 'spine' of the first index of the data points. I can't figure out how to separate the ticks from that first spine and have them always be a vertical column.

I can't seem to find much in there documentation but I have noticed that some examples have this functionality! The only difference being the version number.

https://codepen.io/etcetera/pen/WNNZYBo - This one has the functionality i want and is an older version.

```
var config = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "Happiness", "Loneliness", "Health","Managing at Home", "Finances", "sdf"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'hi',
      data: [8, 8, 7, 10, 10, 9],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    startAngle: 750,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    scale: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      ticks: {
        max: 10,
        suggestedMin: 7,
        min: 0,
      }
    },
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas"), config);
};
```

https://codepen.io/etcetera/pen/QWWqJep - This is the version I'm running and can't separate it.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  "type":"radar",
  "data": {
    "labels":["Online safety group","Online safety responsibilities","Governors","Policy development","Policy Scope",],
    "datasets":[
      {
        "label":"Current Level","backgroundColor":"rgba(30,150,0,0.1)",
        "borderColor":"#1E9600","pointBorderColor":"#1E9600","pointBackgroundColor":"#1E9600",
        "data":[4,1,1,1,4,3],
        "hitRadius":10,
        "hoverRadius":10
      },
    ]
  },
  "options":  {
    "startAngle": 750,
    "aintainAspectRatio": false,
    "animationSteps":60,
    "scale":{
      "pointLabels":{
        "fontSize":14
      },
      "gridLines":  {
        "color":"#CCC",
        "circular":false,
       },
      "ticks":{
        "stepSize":2,
        "fontSize":14,
        "fontColor":"#000",
        "reverse":true,
        "min":1,
        "max":6
      }
    },
    "legend":{
      "labels":{
        "fontSize":10,
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I've tried installing the older version but to no avail the ticks are still 'tied' to that first index 'spine'.

Comment: I've copied your code over to this codepen: https://codepen.io/dracine/pen/XRXooG
and it seem to be working, really looks like only a bug on your version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit Looks like what i was looking for to them was a bug which they ref'd and *fixed here. https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/4682